# Eclipse theme is stuck as a basic flat theme

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

I opened eclipse up on my VM which has ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.

It looks like this [image: http://puu.sh/7Sr79.jpg]

I have no idea how to revert it back to the nicer looking version

Answer (score 0):

Preferences > General > Appearance

You will see three options, swap and pick what fits u

Good luck